# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So i keep getting error from react-native like this

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `LoadScreen`.
> But when i checked on the LoadScreen.js I found no problem or warning from the file
> here is the code in LoadScreen.js

```
> /* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */ import React from 'react'; import {View, StatusBar, Navigator, LogBox} from 'react-native';

import Home from './Home'; import ChatView from '../components/WAcomp/ChatView'; // import ProfileView from '../components/WAcomp/ProfileView'; import CallScreen from '../components/WAcomp/CallScreen';

// console.disableYellowBox = true; LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();


class LoadScreen extends React.Component {   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderScene = this.renderScene.bind(this);   }
    
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'ChatView':
        return (
          <ChatView
            {...this.props}
            id="ChatView"
            navigator={navigator}
            name={route.name}
            image={route.image}
          />
        );
      // case 'ProfileView':
      //   return (
      //     <ProfileView
      //       id="ProfileView"
      //       navigator={navigator}
      //       name={route.name}
      //       image={route.image}
      //       status={route.status}
      //     />
      //   );
      case 'CallScreen':
        return (
          <CallScreen
            id="CallScreen"
            navigator={navigator}
            name={route.name}
            image={route.image}
          />
        );
      default:
        return <Home id="Home" navigator={navigator} />;
    }   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ece5dd'}}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={{id: 'Home'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          configureScene={(route, routeStack) => {
            if (route.id === 'CallScreen') {
              return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid;
            }
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );   } }

export default LoadScreen;
```

and here where i import and call the LoadScreen on my APP

```
    import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

import Button from '../components/Button';
import HeaderWA from '../components/HeaderWA';
import Home from './Home';
import LoadScreen from './LoadScreen';

export default function Dashboard({navigation}) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <Logo /> */}
      {/* <Header>Let’s start</Header> */}
      <HeaderWA navigation={navigation} />
      <LoadScreen />
      {/* <Button
        mode="outlined"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{name: 'StartScreen'}],
          })
        }>
        Logout
      </Button> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

can someone help me?... i seacrh but found no solution and don't find any error on mycode
here is the error on the emulator
[image]

Here is the export on CallSCreen

```
   /* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const CallScreen = props => (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={styles.topBar}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Icon name="whatshot" color="#c3c3c3" size={14} />
        <Text style={styles.subText}>WHATSAPP CALL</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{props.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.subText}>CALLING</Text>
    </View>
    <Image source={{uri: props.image}} style={styles.image}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigator.pop()}>
        <View style={styles.icon}>
          <Icon name="call-end" color="#c3c3c3" size={30} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Image>
    <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
      <Icon name="volume-up" color="#c3c3c3" size={30} />
      <Icon name="chat" color="#c3c3c3" size={30} />
      <Icon name="mic-off" color="#c3c3c3" size={30} />
    </View>
  </View>
);

export default CallScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#075e54',
    height: 140,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  image: {
    width,
    height: 400,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#e20e30',
    marginTop: 250,
  },
  bottomBar: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#075e54',
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    color: '#f0efef',
    fontSize: 36,
  },
  subText: {
    color: '#c8c8c8',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});
```

Comment: The error is saying you've likely messed up an import in `LoadScreen`. Can you share how you export `ChatView`, `CallScreen`, and `Home` components?

Comment: To add to comment from @DrewReese Navigator  and LogBox are not part of React-Native you should check the imports of those too

Comment: I will provide the export @DrewReese , I have Commented it and still show the same error

Comment: @DrewReese I have provide the Export

Comment: Well, since there are several, comment them all out in the `renderScene` function and render something simple, like `Text` that you know should work. Iteratively add a component back in and test if it breaks. This should help you narrow down the component with the mixed up import or missing export.

Comment: @DrewReese okay its working when i commented renderScene, but when i put Text Component it wont Show up/.....,only a blank white screen